# How to rotate column names in pandas table to latex method?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I want to create a latex table from a pandas DataFrame, but column names are long, and I want to put them vertically, like this:

[image: table]

Currently I am using the `to_latex` method, but I do not how to rotate the labels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work by creating a new list based on the column names with the latex command to rotate by 90° and give this list as parameter for the headers:

```py
df.to_latex(escape=False,header=['\\rotatebox{90}{' + c + '}' for c in df.columns]))
```

Comment: Just make sure there are no characters in the column names which need escape characters. If such exist, then do something like so header=['\\rotatebox{90}{' + "\\_".join(c.split("_")) + '}' for c in df.columns